# How to filter job queries?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, filtering

There have been a couple of discussions here whether job posting of *some companies* should not be allowed and things haven't come to a clear end. On the other hand, can we ignore certain companies within a query?

Is this a good enough proposal if not implemented yet? Say I'd like to ignore all offers from "CrossOlder", how would I achieve that?

Comment: Not sure about ignoring a company. But, we have [options](http://stackoverflow.com/help/search-jobs) to filter by a company name.  example→ `company:"stack overflow"`.

Comment: My question is specifically for igoring a company by name

Answer (score 4):

You can currently exclude companies by name using our search syntax feature. For example, you can exclude job listings from Stack Overflow by typing `-company:"Stack Overflow"` in the keyword field.

We're currently wrapping up research/design for updated search functionality and UI. We'll be making features such as this one more accessible and easy-to-use.

Comment: My query is modified, but I can still see it in advertisement. Is it possible to use the query in job advertisement on StackOverflow?